# AWS Glue Script - Get Data from S3 Excel file with multiple Sheets and convert them each to parquet using Pyspark or Python

Tags: excel, python-2.7, amazon-s3, pyspark, aws-glue

i have Excel file names Emp_Data.xlsx contaning 3 Sheets in S3 bucket in loaction as below:

**Location :**s3://Employee/Data/Emp_Data.xlsx

Ask : Acces the excel file in Aws Glue Script using Pyspark or python and convert each sheet to a dataframe and then to a parquet file with the sheet name and place it in the S3 bucket.

**Excel File attached as image.**

[image]

Request to help me with the code for the same

Thanks
Richard

Comment: Kindly let me know if some one has a solution fo this

Answer (score 0):

You need an extra spark-package which is called **com.crealytics.spark.excel**
for this purpose.

However I wouldn't recommend you to use this type of packages with AWS-Glue since every Glue version has its own Python, Spark and Scala versions it can support. Can be seen here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/release-notes.html

If you really need to use Glue then, converting your excels to separate .csv files a simple script would be wiser. Then you can easily use Spark with Glue.

But anyway if these options don't suit you here is the answer. But remember, you can encounter with many errors on the way like Glue, Python, Spark, Scala and extra spark-package versions.

1- As far as I know, all Glue versions support only Scala 2.11 so, you should download **com.crealytics.spark.excel_2.11:0.13.7** package to your local and upload it to s3.

2- Create a Glue-Spark job, choose Glue version 2.0 since, I tried with 3.0 but couldn't make it work.

3- Add your .jars s3 path to "Libraries-Dependent JARs path" tab.

4- Create your sparkSession with glueContext like below:

```py
   spark_context = SparkContext()
   glue_context = GlueContext(spark_context)
   spark_session = glue_context.spark_session
```

5- Read the excel file

```py
   df = (spark_session.read.format("com.crealytics.spark.excel")
         .option("header", "true")
         .option("inferSchema", "true")
         .option("dataAddress", "Sheet1")
         .load("s3a://<your_excel_file's_path>"))
```

Thanks.

Comment: Hi Eren Thanks for the response looks like they are lots of dependency over AWS glue on python and Scalar ,doesent seem to be working. Thanks for the response.Let me know if you have any thing else which would acces an excel file .Im surprised to see that its this difficullt to connect to an excel.

Comment: Did you give it a try? It worked for me. If you got an error, I'd like to help. By the way no matter you use Glue or not, Spark doesn't support excel file read directly, you will always need an extra spark-package. Lastly, did you try Glue Python job with Pandas?

Comment: i have posted my code kindly help me it thts correct

Comment: 1- spark can't read s3:// path directly. You should show the path to spark as s3a://.

Comment: 2- If the error prints like "load" or "scala" related stuff. Then, your .jar file is wrong or corrupted. Please, download it from here as a .zip. https://jar-download.com/artifacts/com.crealytics/spark-excel_2.11/0.13.7/source-code then unzip it and upload all the sub .jars to s3. Finally give all these .jars to Libraries-Dependent JARs path like s3://.../SparseBitSet-1.2.jar,s3://.../...,s3://.../...

Comment: Thanks Eren would test it and update you.

Comment: Seems like we have lot of dependencies Iren would godhead with CSV and thanks for the help